# Simple websocket server from scratch is not working

Tags: perl, websocket

Created a simple websocket server using perl from scratch, when pointing to it from Chrome (by using [echo test](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html)), got error `Error during WebSocket handshake: Incorrect 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header value`.

Pretty sure the key returned for websocket handshake is correct.  Any ideas?

```
use IO::Socket;
use IO::Select;
use Digest::SHA1  qw(sha1 sha1_hex sha1_base64);


$servSock = IO::Socket::INET->new( Proto    => 'tcp',
                                 LocalPort => 8080,
                                Reuse     => 1,
                                Listen    => 500
   ) || die "failed to setup outsock $@\n";
$s = IO::Select->new();
$s -> add ($servSock);
my @readySocks;
while (1) {
   @readySocks = $s->can_read(5);
   foreach $sock (@readySocks) {
      if ($sock eq $servSock)
      {
          #print "inSock\n";
          $clientSock = $servSock->accept();
          setsockopt($clientSock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, 1);
          $s->add ($clientSock);
      } else
      {
         #print "outsock\n";
        $buff = "";
         $fromAddr = recv $sock, $buff, 1470, 0;
         if (length($buff) <= 0)
         {
             $s->remove($sock);
             close $sock; $numOfConns --;
             next;
         }
         printf "recved %d bytes\n", length($buff);
         if ($buff =~ /Sec-WebSocket-Key: (\S+)/) {
             $str = $1;
             print "key is $str|\n";
             my $str = sha1_base64($str . "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11");
             send ($sock, qq{HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r
Connection: Upgrade\r
Upgrade: websocket\r
Sec-Websocket-Accept: $str\r
\r\n}, 0);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Note: I need to create one from scratch as part of another project.

**Update**

Thanks to the suggestion from @steffen-ullrich,  changed it from

```
send ($sock, qq{HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r
Connection: Upgrade\r
Upgrade: websocket\r
Sec-Websocket-Accept: $str\r
\r\n}, 0);
```

to (note there `$str` is now `$str=`)

```
send ($sock, qq{HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r
Connection: Upgrade\r
Upgrade: websocket\r
Sec-Websocket-Accept: $str=\r
\r\n}, 0);
```

made it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation of sha1_bas64](https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::SHA1#sha1_base64($data,...)):

> Note that the base64 encoded string returned is **not padded** to be a multiple of 4 bytes long. If you want interoperability with other base64 encoded sha1 digests you might want to **append the redundant string "=" to the result**.

And adding '=' as described is what your code is missing.